# The command was not found or was not executable: .sh // /bin/chmod: No such file or directory

Tags: shell, ansible, benchmarking

I am trying to run a shell script and become an error:

```
 "The command was not found or was not executable: chdir=/home/cloudera/Documents/TPCx-BB/bin/TPCxBB_Benchmarkrun.sh."
```

The script is in this folder, so it has to be that it is not executable. It has the following permission:

```
chmod 777 -R /home/cloudera/Documents/TPCx-BB/bin/TPCxBB_Benchmarkrun.sh
```

The script begins with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

and I am running it from ansible as follows:

```
command: chdir=/home/cloudera/Documents/TPCx-BB/bin/TPCxBB_Benchmarkrun.sh
```

I have found a possible solution to run the command like this:

But then I get the following error:

```
"/bin/chmod: cannot access 'chdir=/home/cloudera/Documents/TPCx-BB/bin/TPCxBB_Benchmarkrun.sh': No such file or directory"
```

Anyone sees what could be the problem?

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You will want to revert to sane permissions (for your use case, probably `chmod 755`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue with: chmod +x ./TPCxBB_Benchmarkrun.sh

Answer (score 1):

`chdir=/home/cloudera/Documents/TPCx-BB/bin/TPCxBB_Benchmarkrun.sh` is obviously not a command you can pass to a shell/command.

Either pass the command full path directly:

```
- name: run my command
  command: /home/cloudera/Documents/TPCx-BB/bin/TPCxBB_Benchmarkrun.sh
```

Or use the `chdir` option correctly:

```
- name: run my command
  command: ./TPCxBB_Benchmarkrun.sh
  args:
    chdir: /home/cloudera/Documents/TPCx-BB/bin
```

For more info and examples: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html

Comment: This is a totally different error that has nothing to do with ansible. Ask an other question. hint: `man pip`

Comment: It is unfortunately not working. Still "msg": "The command was not found or was not executable: ./TPCxBB_Benchmarkrun.sh."

Comment: Did you check that the file exists in the directory ? Did you check that the file is executable for the user lauching the task ?

Comment: Yes, I did check. It was there. I resolved the issue, I had to add: chmod +x ./TPCxBB_Benchmarkrun.sh